# How to print an object on page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am have a big piece of data (list) stored in the state that I want to print out on my page in react.

I have tried -

```
<div>{JSON.stringify(myObject)}</div>
```

and

```
<div>{myObject.toString()}</div>
```

`toString()` does not work, but i thought i would give it a shot. I am unsure how to do this, I know if I was in angular I could store the object in a `$scope` variable, and just do `{{myVar}}` on the page to render the object. Is there any way to do this quickly in react?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I think your example should work. Not sure what kind of representation you are hoping for but I put an example on jsfiddle where I use JSON.stringify to print out an object.

https://jsfiddle.net/5yq9fev6/1/

```
var world = {
    'abc' : [1, 2, 3],
    'b': {
        1: 'c'
     }
}

var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>        
                <div>{JSON.stringify(world)}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

React.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: there is a better way:
`return (<div><pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2) }</pre></div>);`

Comment: @Filomat That is exactly what I was looking for (the <pre> tag)

Answer (score 16):

As a function component with `JSON.stringify` additional arguments for indentation

```
import React from 'react';

var person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  age: 50,
  eyeColor: "blue"
};

const StringifyObject = () => (
  <pre>
    {JSON.stringify(person, null, 2)}
  </pre>
)
```